# An Error when execute : sapply(iris,unique) [R]

Tags: r

There are 5 columns in "iris", which are Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width & Species. I have make a few tries as follows:

1. The function of unique() in each column was workable.
2. The function of sapply() was also good when I used the FUN as mean. However, I got an Error when I try to use the FUN as unique.

```html
    sapply(iris,unique)

    $Sepal.Length
     [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.4 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.2 5.5 4.5 5.3 7.0 6.4 6.9 6.5 6.3 6.6 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 6.2
    [28] 6.8 7.1 7.6 7.3 7.2 7.7 7.4 7.9

    $Sepal.Width
     [1] 3.5 3.0 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 2.9 3.7 4.0 4.4 3.8 3.3 4.1 4.2 2.3 2.8 2.4 2.7 2.0 2.2 2.5 2.6

    $Petal.Length
     [1] 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.7 1.6 1.1 1.2 1.0 1.9 4.7 4.5 4.9 4.0 4.6 3.3 3.9 3.5 4.2 3.6 4.4 4.1 4.8 4.3 5.0 3.8 3.7 5.1
    [28] 3.0 6.0 5.9 5.6 5.8 6.6 6.3 6.1 5.3 5.5 6.7 6.9 5.7 6.4 5.4 5.2

    $Petal.Width
     [1] 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.1 0.5 0.6 1.4 1.5 1.3 1.6 1.0 1.1 1.8 1.2 1.7 2.5 1.9 2.1 2.2 2.0 2.4 2.3

    $Species
    [1] setosa     versicolor virginica 

    Error in if (n <= 1L || lenl[n] <= width) n else max(1L, which.max(lenl >  : 
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

It's seen that sapply() and unique() have already done their works, but why the Error was showed on the console? I have tried to use "option(error=recover)";however, I couldn't figure it out.... Is it because the class of the Species is factor? How can I make it work?

Actually, I meet the same problem when I take the lesson of swirl. It has stocked me for few days...Could anyone help me to solve the problem? I will appreciate for your help. Thanks.

Comment: It works for me without the error. Could you please `Sys.info()`?

Comment: What I'm using is Win10, R-3.5.2, RStudio-1.1.463.  
I also meet the same problem when I go through the swirl Lesson10 (82%) lappy(  , unique)  & Lesson11 (16%) sappy(   , unique).

Comment: I tested it in both Linux and Win10, with the same RStudio and R version, it showed no errors. Run `rm(list = ls())` and close all projects and files in RStudio then repeat your code. Do not save the Workspace image changes after manipulation of original data which are required for other tests.

Comment: I switch the version to R-3.3.3. It works without the error!!! I think the issue is inside the newest version of R (R-3.5.2).