# about errors when making a list

Tags: r, list

I got some problems about making a data set(list). I have never before seen
this error message:

```
Error in if (n <= 1L || lenl[n] <= width) n else max(1L, which.max(lenl >  : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed /// whenever print the 'Bita_quiz'
```

I have tried to know what the message mean is by googling or surfing. but
I can't find any idea.

Is there any someone to help me why the error code happening ?

```
bita_quiz_score <- c(90,30,70,60,80)
bita_quiz_grade <- factor(c('1등급','3등급','2등급','2등급','1등급'),order = T, levels=c('3등급','2등급','1등급'))
Bita_quiz <- list(bita_quiz_score,bita_quiz_grade)
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't even contains the line in which error is happening, please provide your complete code and error message

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Similar error has happened for another user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637177/an-error-when-execute-sapplyiris-unique-r

Comment: @manniB l Above code is all , ,, that's all. The error message is also all. 
Because I wanted to know that the error code is happening on all people, I share above  code . Some friends have same error code, but as like you, other friends don't get any error. What do you think about this problems ?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Above code is all , ,, that's all. The error message is also all. 
Because I wanted to know that the error code is happening on all people, I share above  code . Some friends have same error code, but as like you, other friends don't get any error. What do you think about this problems ?